# NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToTypeMismatchException: Can not return value of type Task`1 for IDbCommand. (expected type Void)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, xunit.net, nsubstitute

I have the below interface, in the application I am using Dapper and I am trying to mock the query and connection using NSubstitude.

```
public interface IDapperContextBuilder
{
    IDbConnection  CreateConnection();
}
```

**In the unit test**

```
[Fact]
        public void GetAllAuthority()
        {
            // Arrange
            var connectionFactory = Substitute.For<IDapperContextBuilder>();
            var fakeConnection = Substitute.For<IDbConnection>();
            connectionFactory.CreateConnection().Returns(fakeConnection);


            // Simulate Dapper behavior
            var authority = new MasterData.Authority();
            fakeConnection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<MasterData.Authority>(Arg.Any<string>()).ReturnsForAnyArgs(authority);

            // rest of the code
        }
```

**In controller**

```
public async Task UpdateStatus(AuthorityStatusUpdateInputDto input)
{
    
    using var connection = _dapperContextBuilder.CreateConnection();
    Authority authority = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<Authority>(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Authority");

    // rest of the code
    
}
```

Keep getting the exception in line `fakeConnection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<MasterData.Authority>(Arg.Any<string>()).ReturnsForAnyArgs(authority);` as

```
Can not return value of type Task`1 for IDbCommand.set_CommandText (expected type Void).

Make sure you called Returns() after calling your substitute (for example: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(value)),
and that you are not configuring other substitutes within Returns() (for example, avoid this: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub())).

If you substituted for a class rather than an interface, check that the call to your substitute was on a virtual/abstract member.
Return values cannot be configured for non-virtual/non-abstract members.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [package](https://github.com/jmg48/NSubstitute.DbConnection)  `NSubstitute.Community.DbConnection`

I tried   with the package:

```
var connectionFactory = Substitute.For<IDapperContextBuilder>();
            var fakeConnection = Substitute.For<IDbConnection>().SetupCommands();
            
            connectionFactory.CreateConnection().Returns(fakeConnection);

            var authority1 = new Authority() { Id = 1, Name = "N1" };
            var authority2 = new Authority() { Id = 2, Name = "N2" }  ;
            
            fakeConnection.SetupQuery("SELECT * FROM Authority").Returns(authority1, authority2);
```

When I debug the test:

[image]

[image]

you could follow the codes in this package for further requirements

Comment: well returning the value is working fine, however, when I return the value facing the issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76880813/system-data-dataexception-error-parsing-column-0-name-null-system-refl. I know this is because of NULL but what can I do in this

Comment: Sounds like this bug on github:https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues/642

Comment: is there any workaround you know about it, really stuck on this.

Comment: Seems like something wrong with the setup, because that code is working fine with the real connection. It is not working only with unit test case NULL. However, with the real connection is working fine